# Access public storage from a Firestore client?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

I'm writing a Firestore app on iOS and I want to access this public store https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/29f98e10-a489-4c82-ae5e-489dbcd4912f;tab=configuration?prefix=&forceOnObjectsSortingFiltering=false

This is published by an open source project and not linked to myself.

When I try to use it with the API for custom storage in swift:

```
let storage = Storage.storage(url: "gs://29f98e10-a489-4c82-ae5e-489dbcd4912f")
```

I get the error:

> A required service account is missing necessary permissions. Please resolve by visiting the Storage page of the Firebase Console and re-linking your Firebase bucket or see this FAQ for more info: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#storage-accounts. If you recently made changes to your service account, please wait a few minutes for the changes to propagate through our systems and try again

However, I do not see how to request access / service account for a public store in my firebase console.

How should I configure my firebase app to access that public storage?